# Why is a number sign-extended when it is cast to an unsigned type?

Tags: c, printf

I was studying how C stores data in memory by bit patterns.
However I have confronted some issues when it comes to `printf` formatting.

I have saved a variable as `-10` (I do understand two's complement)
and another variable as `246`. Those two variables have bit patterns of `11110110` (which is `0xF6`).

I was trying to print out a value using the `unsigned int` hexadecimal format in `printf`.

```
char a = -10; 
unsigned char b = 246;

printf("a : %x , b : %x\n" , (unsigned int) a, (unsigned int) b);
//a : fffffff6 , b : f6
```

Both integers have the same bit pattern of `0xF6`. However, if I do perform type casting into `unsigned int`, the result varies. The result is `0xFFFFFFF6` for `a`, while `b` remains the same.

For a signed character, it seems to me that type casting process made the `unsigned char` into an integer and filled all the empty bits with 1.

Is this due to their signedness? Or is this just Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Yes. Sign bit extends left when promoted to a larger signed integral type. Hence all 1 bits. Unsigned integral type has no sign bit, hence all zeroes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Is the sign-bit extended upon a cast to a larger unsigned type?

Comment: @JL2210 Sorry for making too much mistakes in my question. I am quite new to this forum and English is not my mother tongue... Thanks a lot for editing my post into more readable form!

Comment: The behaviour you're seeing is correct, and your expectations are wrong.   `(unsigned)(-10) == UINT_MAX - 9`.   The result you expect (incorrectly) presumes that `(unsigned)(-10) == UCHAR_MAX - 9`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this expression

```
(unsigned int) a
```

the integer promotions are applied to the object `a`.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or
> unsigned int may be used:
>
> — An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or
> unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
> the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> — A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
> otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
> integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

and

> 3 **The integer promotions preserve value including sign**. As discussed
> earlier, whether a ‘‘plain’’ char is treated as signed is
> implementation-defined.

If you want that in the result object after casting the character object would be represented as having the type `unsigned char` then you have to write

```
(unsigned char) a
```

As the value of the promoted expression `(unsigned char) a` can be represented in the type `unsigned int` then the second cast (to `unsigned int`) is not required. The C Standard allows to use arguments pf the type `int` instead of the type `unsigned int` if the value is represented in the both types.  You could just write

```
printf("a : %x , b : %x\n" , (unsigned char) a, (unsigned int) b);
```

Comment: Does this mean that since the original object had sign bit, by type casting from signed character to signed int makes the empty bits become filled 1 due to the preservation of values including sign?

Comment: @Gooday2die Yes casting a signed integer object to unsigned int object with a gretaer size propogates the sign bit.

Comment: @Gooday2die: No. The C standard defines these conversions by the **values** represented by the objects, not by the patterns of their bits. Almost all modern C implementation use two’s complement, in which the bits that result from converting a signed type to an unsigned type are the same bits that result from propagating the sign bit. However, the C standard also allows one’s complement and sign and magnitude. When these are in use, conversions follow the rules for values, not any rules for propagating bits.

Comment: Vlad, do I understand now that in `(unsigned int) a` of the signed `char a`, _first_ `a` is promoted to a larger integral type to be an argument of a function call, and _then_ is interpreted for the remainder to be an `unsigned int` (which is not required as there is no remaining expression)?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie a is converted to the type unsigned int propogate the sign bit in the 2's complement representation. Using ( unsigned char )a a is now is interpretated as unsigned char and due to the casting the sign bit is not propogated because now a does not have the sign bit. It is a value bit..

Comment: This is incorrect; the integer promotions are only applied in contexts where the standard says "The integer promotions are applied..." or equivalent wording   (For example `sizeof a` does not apply the integer promotions to `a`).   The definition of casting does not specify that the integer promotions are applied to the operand.   The behaviour of `(unsigned int)a`  goes directly to C11 6.3.1.3/2  " the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type"